# Select any column with respect to cell containing

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named a. Some cells containing a string 'Empty' in many columns. I want to find this columns. Can you help me?.

Comment: sample data and output will be helpful

Comment: Please post the table structure, sample data and expected result.

Comment: sample Table: Column1: a,b,c,'EMPTY',e,f;   Column2:a,b,c,d,e,f;                         Column3: a,b,c,d,e,,'EMPTY'; Column4: a,b,c,d,e,f;   Column5:a,b,'EMPTY',c,d,e,f;    Column6: a,b,c,d,e,f ; .......etc.... Total no.of columns: 150, I want  select each column containing ,'EMPTY', in any  cell.

Comment: Do you want to select a _column_ if it contains `EMPTY` anywhere, or do you want rows?  Typically, queries return a fixed set of columns, with a variable number of rows, not the other way around.

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to include sample data. Preferably, lay it out *as a table* and then highlight it and hit the `{}` button so that it's presented as code which maintains its layout. As you've probably observed, it's *not* easy to read sample data if it's here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this dynamic query, it will check all the columns with character data and list the columns which has the word 'Empty'.

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(50) = 'Empty'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'MAX(CASE WHEN ' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' LIKE ''%'+ @SearchText +'%'' THEN ''' + c.COLUMN_NAME +''' ELSE '''' END) + '','' + '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and c.TABLE_NAME = 'a' 
    AND c.DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar','sysname')

SET @sql = @sql + ''''' FROM dbo.a'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
WHERE a.col1 LIKE '%Empty%' OR a.col2 LIKE '%Empty%' OR ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In sql server you can get object id of table then using that object id you can fetch columns. In that case it will be as below:

**Step 1:** First get Object Id of table

```
select * from sys.tables order by name
```

**Step 2**: Now get columns of your table and search in it:

```
 select * from a where 'Empty' in (select name from sys.columns  where  object_id =1977058079)
```

Note: object_id is what you get fetch in first step for you relevant table

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest dynamic SQL

--First you set the variable `@TableName` to your actual table's name.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)='a';
```

--The following statement will create a list of all columns with a data type containing the word "char" (others should not hold the value `Empty`)

```
DECLARE @ColList VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ' OR ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' LIKE ''%empty%''' 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%'
        FOR XML PATH('')
     ),1,4,'');
```

--This statement builds a command

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM [' + @TableName + '] WHERE ' + @ColList
);
```

--Here you can see the command

```
PRINT @cmd;
```

--And here it is executed

```
EXEC(@cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using unpivot with an help of dynamic query , here i have done below an working sample for you , there might be some modification you might have to do to put the below psedo code with your working .

> Sample table structure been used :

```
create table ColTest
(
name1 varchar(10),
name2 varchar(10),
name3 varchar(10),
name4 varchar(10)
)
insert into  ColTest values ('sdas','asdasda','ewrewr','erefds')
insert into  ColTest values ('sdas','asdasda','EMPTY','erefds')
insert into  ColTest values ('EMPTY','asdasda','ewrewr','erefds')



DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
SELECT @table_name = 'ColTest'

DECLARE @tmpTable SYSNAME
SELECT @tmpTable = 'ColTest2'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
SELECT * into 
 ' + @tmpTable + '
FROM ' + @table_name + '
UNPIVOT (
    cell_value FOR column_name IN (
        ' + STUFF((
    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
    FROM sys.columns c WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT i.[object_id], i.column_id
        FROM sys.index_columns i WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE i.index_id = 1
    ) i ON c.[object_id] = i.[object_id] AND c.column_id = i.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
        AND i.[object_id] IS NULL
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + '
    )
) unpiv'




PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

select * from ColTest2 where cell_value = 'EMPTY'
```